# (Solved) Ubuntu 16.04 Grub gone waking from suspend while leaving USB with txtdocuments in slot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, suspend

I managed to get Ubuntu 16.04 installed on a Lenovo Ideapad 100 with windows 10 preinstalled. I removed the USB with the Ubuntu image and installed some of the advised extra Ubuntu softwarepackages

Now the next thing happened:
Today I work on textfiles from a different USBstick that I've stuck in the slot on my computer. That was new. I did not do that in the days before today, when my Ubuntu 16.04 mounted without a problem.
So while this USBstick with only textfiles was mounted, my computer went into sleep (coffeebreak)
When waking from suspend my computer restarted in Windows 10 so I could not get to Ubuntu.

Then, in the hope to get it fixed, I shut my laptop down and restarted it. But the GRUB is gone.
That step is surpassed completely.
The Lenovo starts up in windows 10 all the time, whatever I try, although I have been working in Ubuntu 16.04 for several days now.

Is there anyone who understands this? Or who can help me?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I figuered it out.

In the UEFI i had to enable start up from USB to get UBUNTU installed.
And I had to put the UEFI in the "Legacy" mode.
And to switch Ubuntu above Windows bootmanager in the EFI menu.(Fn + F10 to save)

However when I start up and any type of USB is in the USB slot.
Windows bootmanager is automatically switched back above UBUNTU in the UEFI.

What I did was put the startup order back and disable start up from USB again.
(Fn + F10 to save) And then, when I start up with an USB in the slot, the startup order in the EFI isn't altered anymore. The Grub is back forgood.
Hope this helps others.

Kind regards